# Easily switch between seeing only lines affecting a running total and all lines

Tags: google-sheets

**Background:**

I have a spreadsheet with one row per date. Each row has a current total **A**, there are different ways to either add or subtract a value from that total.

No other column except **G** (for **A**, the current total) contains any calculations. And each **G** cell just subtracts and adds to the previous value. For example **G3** `=G2+C3-D3+E3-F3`.

**Problem:**

Since most of the rows do not affect **A** in any way I'd like to have a way of only seeing those rows that actually change **A** (marked below in example). It has to be easy and quick to switch between viewing all rows and only the lines where **A** is changed.

[image: Example spreadsheet with the lines that changes A marked]

If it is possible I'd like to do it without introducing another column that indicates if the row should be seen or not. However, the most **important thing is that it's quick to work with so that I can easily switch between all rows and those changing A**. If could be a filter, a filter view, a separate or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a filter view with filter by condition  "Custom formula is", `=sum(C2:F2)`. It does not matter which column the filter is placed at.

[image: condition]

#### Explanation

The filter takes place starting with the second row (header row is not filtered). Therefore, the custom formula should be written as it will be applied to the second row; the references will be automatically remapped for other rows.

If the value of a formula is 0, the row is omitted from the view. If it is anything else, the row remains in the view.

Comment: Worked like a charm! (my up-vote will be seen once I gain rep)